# How to identify email = outlook.createitem (0) in the def escrever(self) function: to be performed in the def Send () function :?

Tags: python

raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self.*username*, attr))
AttributeError: outlook.application.Attachments

```
class EnviarEmail:
  def escrever(self):

      email = outlook.CreateItem(0)

      destino = self.entry_descricao.get()
      assunto = self.entry_assunto.get()      
      texto = self.entry_texto.get("1.0", END)

      email.To = f"{destino}"
      email.Subject = f"{assunto}"
      email.HTMLBody = f"""
      <p>{texto}</p>
      """

  def enviar():

      email = outlook

      email.Attachments.Add(os.getcwd()  + "\\anexos.zip")
            
      email.Send()

  def executar():

     if os.path.exists("anexos.zip"):

        EnviarEmail.escrever(self)

        EnviarEmail.enviar()

EnviarEmail()
```

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ALPHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\ALPHA\Desktop\Enviar arquivo\Programa de envio de email\APPDAFABIANA.py", line 86, in zip
    EnviarEmail.enviar()
  File "c:\Users\ALPHA\Desktop\Enviar arquivo\Programa de envio de email\APPDAFABIANA.py", line 63, in enviar
    email.Attachments.Add(os.getcwd()  + "\\anexos.zip")
  File "C:\Users\ALPHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 639, in __getattr__
```

Comment: There's a bunch of things not correct in this, I'm a bit hesitant as to where to start. Two functions are missing the `self` keyword. The variable `email` is declared as a local variable, not class variable. What is `outlook`? I highly advise you to read up on classes and how to use them, [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp) would be a good place for example...

Comment: When I removed the Email = Outlook variable and I used Self Keyword in the two functions. It worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
    class EnviarEmail:
      def escrever(self):

      email = outlook.CreateItem(0)

      destino = self.entry_descricao.get()
      assunto = self.entry_assunto.get()      
      texto = self.entry_texto.get("1.0", END)

      email.To = f"{destino}"
      email.Subject = f"{assunto}"
      email.HTMLBody = f"""
      <p>{texto}</p>
      """

  def enviar(self):

     self.email.Attachments.Add(os.getcwd()  + "\\anexos.zip")
            
     self.email.Send()

  def executar(self):

     if os.path.exists("anexos.zip"):

        EnviarEmail.escrever(self)

        EnviarEmail.enviar(self)

EnviarEmail()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).